# I blow out devil's flame like blowing out candles, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I have a complicated origin. 
>   My father is Omani Hungarian, while mother is Russian. 
>   I have three engines, only one for driving.
>   What makes me was in the army, but now I fight against a different enemy. 
>   I blow wind and water. 
>   I blow out devil's flame like blowing out candles. 
>   My first job done in a greasy, scorching inferno in a desert, alongside a gulf. 
>   I was under one year old, and showed up in a documentary that almost won an Academy Award.

What am I?

Comment: "Omani Hungarian" or "Romani Hungarian"?

Comment: @randal'thor Though it looks like a typo, but it is "Omani Hungarian". The solution does not have connection with Romania.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is ungrammatical to the point of being nonsensical in places (eg "without organism", "done in a black"), and the errors do not appear to be an intended part of the puzzle.

Comment: @AE Hold on, could you let me edit the riddle? I lost some detail and I can fix it now.

Comment: Riddle updated, hoping it can be solved.

Comment: @AE Poor grammar is a reason to edit a question, not to close it. It was still quite clear what the OP meant, even from the beginning.

Comment: Hi @randal'thor - I don't agree that the parts I quoted had a clear meaning (that's why I quoted them - what does "done in a black" or "without organism" mean? Now it's edited, does "aloneside" mean "alone" or "alongside"?). Now the sandbox is gone again we're getting a lot of riddles written with very poor English - downvoting doesn't seem to have much effect - I'm open to suggestions as to how we should deal with this problem.

Comment: @AE "in a black, scorching inferno" - presumably the inferno was somehow black? "Frankenstein without organism" - without a living organism, in some way? I don't get the exact meaning, but hey, it's a riddle - not getting the exact meaning is what it's all about! :-) And surely "alongside" would make far more sense than "alone" in that sentence.

Comment: Re the sandbox: well, firstly, [it isn't gone](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5276/5373), so you can always link people to it and suggest they post their riddle there to get it improved. For how to deal with low-quality riddles in general, there's [a featured meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5372/5373). As for poor English in particular: **edit it**; or if it's totally incomprehensible and you've no idea how to edit it, downvote and move on. Personally I've upvoted this, but will happily change to a downvote if it turns out to be bad once the solution appears.

Comment: And now that an answer has been accepted, I stand by my upvote. The riddle isn't very poetic, but it does have a solution which is clearly correct once found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> [Big Wind, the oil well fire tank.](http://www.caranddriver.com/features/stilling-the-fires-of-war)

I have a complicated origin.

My father is Omani Hungarian, while mother is Russian.

> From the article: "This unique firefighting tank, which is fondly called "Big Wind" by some and "Windy" by others, has its own multicultural history. The tank is Russian, the owner is the Arab-owned Hungarian company MB Drilling, a division of the MB Group of Oman, and it was created in 1991 in a town 50 miles southeast of Budapest."

I have three engines, only one for driving.

> Two are for blowing air/water onto the oil well fire.

What makes me was in the army, but now I fight against a different enemy.

> This thing is a tank!

I blow wind and water.

> With those two extra engines.

I blow out devil's flame like blowing out candles.

> Oil well fires are nasty stuff!

My first job done in a greasy, scorching inferno in a desert, alongside a gulf.

> Putting out fires in the Persian Gulf

I was under one year old, and showed up in a documentary that almost won an Academy Award.

> [Fires of Kuwait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fires_of_Kuwait)

Comment: Correct answer! I will have a better riddle next time.